# Remove dynamic control

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a form with dynamic added controls. When the user clicks next all dynamic controls have to be removed. My code only removes some of them.

for example `dtxt2` does not get removed the first time but if I run the remove function a second time it does get removed.

This is the function to add the dynamics:

```
void TextboxesStep21()
{
    removeDynamics();
     TextBox dtxt1 = new TextBox();
     dtxt1.Name = "DynamicTextBox1";
     dtxt1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(336, 125);
     dtxt1.Text = ((diameterOfDrivingWeel + spindleSlope)*10).ToString();
     this.Controls.Add(dtxt1);
     
    TextBox dtxt2 = new TextBox();
    dtxt2.Name = "DynamicTextBox2";
    dtxt2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(336, 148);
    dtxt2.Text = gearingRatioDen.ToString();
    this.Controls.Add(dtxt2);

    TextBox dtxt3 = new TextBox();
    dtxt3.Name = "DynamicTextBox3";
    dtxt3.Text = gearingRatioNum.ToString(); ;
    dtxt3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(336, 171);
    this.Controls.Add(dtxt3);


    pictureBox1.SendToBack();
    pictureBox2.SendToBack();
}
```

This is my remove function

```
void removeDynamics()
{
    foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
    {
        if (x.Name.Contains("Dynamic"))
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(x);
            x.Dispose(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you aren't removing the control from the Controls list. I doubt that simply disposing it is enough.

Comment: @MattBreckon I have added: " this.Controls.Remove(x);" before my dispose this does make a difference but still does not remove all Dynamic textboxes.

Comment: is it windows forms? may be you should include the tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> for example dtxt2 does not get removed the first time but if I run the remove function a second time it does get removed.
> ... if you have time could you further explain what my fault was?

When you iterate through a collection you have an iterator in the background that holds the current position and is checked against the length of the collection. So if the collection has 3 items and the iterator is at the position 2

```
[X1] [X2] [X3]  // Length 3
      ^
      |
   iterator
```

Now you remove the second element

```
[X1] [X3]  // Length 2
      ^
      |
   iterator
```

the iterator has still its value, but now it is pointing to the next element, and unfortunately this is the last in the collection. Now the loop will increment the iterator and check whether it is already larger than the amount of items in the collection. If so it will cancel the loop, because there are no more items to iterate. X3 is thus never processed

```
[X1] [X3]      // Length 2
           ^
           |
        iterator
```

This is why your second textbox got skipped in the first place.

when removing items from a collection during iteration through the collection one would use a reversed loop. starting from the end and going down to 0:

```
void removeDynamics()
{
    for (int i = this.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Control x = this.Controls[i];
        if (x.Name.Contains("Dynamic"))
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(x);
            x.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

You could of course also filter the controls collection and get only the matching items first and then remove them:

```
List<TextBox> toBeRemoved = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                         .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Dynamic")).ToList();
toBeRemoved.ForEach(x => { this.Controls.Remove(x); x.Dispose(); });
```

Comment: thank you for this very clear explanation!! now that I read it its all super logical. This will for sure help me in the future

Answer (score 1):

You're amending the `Controls` collection while you're iterating it. You can use LINQ's `ToList()` to generate a separate collection that you can iterate instead.

```
void removeDynamics()
{
    foreach (Control x in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList())
    {
         if (x.Name.Contains("Dynamic"))
         {
             this.Controls.Remove(x);
             x.Dispose(); 
         }
    }
}
```

In fact, since you're now using LINQ. You might as well only pull the controls you want:

```
void removeDynamics()
{
    foreach (Control x in this.Controls.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Dynamic")).ToList())
    {
         this.Controls.Remove(x);
         x.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to make a list of all active controls first then? Because controls does not contain the funtion toList();

Comment: add `using System.Linq`

Comment: `Controls` is a weird collection. You can only apply linq methods and `ToList` after a call of `OfType<TextBox>()`. Sorry mate but your answer does not compile

Comment: I have System.linq added. But it still does not know .toList() or for your better option the .Where

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer thank you for the code if you have time could you further explain what my fault was? I do not fully understand what you mean with amending

Comment: Ah nice one @MongZhu, thanks. Apologies for the bad example.

Comment: @JoeriE It's generally a bad idea to iterate a collection at the same time you're changing it, because the enumerator can get confused as to which is the next item.